# Expand keyval into TikZ's node optional argument

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3, latex3, optional-arguments

I am willing to create matrix-like nodes, so I implemented a draft function `\DrawMatrixx` below.

Also, I have general style for nodes called `Matrixx/body` for matrix, or body, itself and for dimensions, i.e. nodes above and left (not in MWE below) w.r.t body, called `Matrixx/dim`.

Generally, I will be okay with those styles, but sometimes I will however need more precise control of node's behavior, which I would like to achieve with `options/body` keyval, for example. And to be able override and expand the default `Matrixz/body` style, I need to place this option after the style — look at commentaries at `\matrixx_draw_node:n`. But in case of `option/body={dashed, text=red}` there will be mistake as expected.

I suspect I could achieve what I want with complicated combination of `\expandafter`'s, but I hope there is much more cleaner way with `expl3`?

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}


\tikzstyle{Matrixx/body}=[
    draw,
    rounded corners,
    inner sep=2pt,
    outer sep=0pt,
]

\tikzstyle{Matrixx/dim}=[
    draw=none,
    font=\footnotesize,
    outer sep=2pt,
    inner sep=3pt
]

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_set:Nn \g_matrixx_minimum_height_tl {1cm}
\tl_set:Nn \g_matrixx_minimum_width_tl {1cm}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DrawMatrixx}{ m }{%
    \matrixx_draw_node:n { #1 }
}

\keys_define:nn { Matrixx }
{%
    name .tl_set:N = \l__matrixx_name_tl,
    minimum height .tl_set:N = \l__matrixx_minimum_height_tl,
    minimum width .tl_set:N = \l__matrixx_minimum_width_tl,
    content .tl_set:N = \l__matrixx_content_tl,
    options/body .tl_set:N = \l_matrixx_options_body_tl,
    options/dim .tl_set:N = \l_matrixx_options_dim_tl
}

\cs_new_protected:Nn \matrixx_draw_node:n 
{%
    \group_begin:

        \keys_set:nn { Matrixx } {
            minimum height=\g_matrixx_minimum_height_tl,
            minimum width=\g_matrixx_minimum_width_tl,
            content=,
            options/body=,
            options/dim=,
            name=,
            #1
        }
        \node[%
            Matrixx/body,
            minimum~height=\l__matrixx_minimum_height_tl,
            minimum~width=\l__matrixx_minimum_width_tl,
            % Here should be expanded \l_matrixx_options_body_tl if any.
        ] (\l__matrixx_name_tl/body) {\l__matrixx_content_tl};

        \node[%
            Matrixx/dim,%
            anchor=south,
            % Here should be expanded \l_matrixx_options_dim_tl if any.
        ] (\l__matrixx_name_tl/dim/top) at (\l__matrixx_name_tl/body.north) {n};
    \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \DrawMatrixx{
        name=Name,
        content=H,
        options/body={%
            thick,
            text=blue,
        },
        options/dim={%
            text=red,
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Thank you.

P.S. Sorry, if the question is as easy as pie, however I was not able to google properly — just started digging into `expl3`, like, today due to more and more frequent meetings with various clear and nice solutions with `expl3` by TeX maestro like *egreg* et al.

Comment: What you want is a `:VVVVVV` variant of a `:nnnnnn` base function. The latter should use the raw args *as passed* (no expansion, just `#1`, `#2`, etc.). But there are a few more things to fix in your code. I had started but lost my work due to a power outage, and have no time anymore now. :-/ Basically, you should probably use `.initial:n` in the `\keys_define` to declare “default” values,  declare your variables with `\tl_new:N`, clarify between public ones and private ones, and probably get rid of the global ones here.

Comment: Also, beware of key names with a space, you need to use `~` under `\ExplSyntaxOn` regime. And some `%` are not needed in your code, precisely because of this regime. You could probably reduce the example to something shorter—that would encourage people to answer.

Comment: Thank you for commentary, @frougon. I will read manuals more precisely and try to apply your suggestions. P.S. Oh, nasty thing you are — power outage! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @frougon, as for your second commentary. Why should I be aware of `~` or where exactly may I read about unpleasant behaviour? And thank you for remark about example's size.

Comment: When you use e.g. `minimum height` in the second arg of `\keys_define:nn`, TeX really sees `minimumheight`, because the arguments of this call of `\keys_define:nn` are tokenized under  `\ExplSyntaxOn` regime (your `\keys_define:nn` call is between `\ExplSyntaxOn` and `\ExplSyntaxOff`). But if the `minimum height` option is later input in the *document body,* where `\ExplSyntaxOn` regime is off, the space won't be ignored, therefore the passed option will be `minimum height` and won't match the declared option, which is `minimumheight`.

Comment: Under `\ExplSyntaxOn` regime, spaces in the input are ignored. You have to use `~` under this regime to get a space. This is normally explained in `expl3.pdf` available [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel). To be clear: under `\ExplSyntaxOn` regime, use `minimum~height` unless you really want the space to be ignored. Unrelated: `\tikzstyle` is deprecated AFAIK, use `\tikzset` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were right to suspect that solving this with `\expandafter` is not in the `expl3` spirit (even if there is an equivalent function in the LaTeX3 language, namely `\exp_args:No`, it often makes code harder to read and maintain than necessary).

## `expl3` control sequence variants

The key concept for answering your question is `expl3` control sequence variants. I suggest you to read *Methods for defining variants* in [The LaTeX3 interfaces](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) available from this [precious “l3kernel” link](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel). In particular, the function `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` is very useful to define variants of standard `expl3` as well as your own functions, and is what you need here.

A `V` argument specifier passes the *value* of the specified variable to the base function. For instance, if you have a token list variable `\l_my_tl` that contains `abc def` and call a function this way:

```latex
\my_function:V \l_my_tl
```

what will happen is that the base function `\my_function:n` will be called with `abc def` (the “value“ of `\l_my_tl`) as its argument. That is to say, in this case, `\my_function:V \l_my_tl` would be equivalent to `\my_function:n { abc~def }` (under `\ExplSyntaxOn` syntax regime), which is *not the same* as `\my_function:n { \l_my_tl }` (in the latter case, the argument is a single token: `\l_my_tl`, whereas `abc~def` is made of 7 tokens).

For this to work, you need to:

1. Define the base function `\my_function:n` which uses its argument as if it were entered “in full” (`abc def`); in other words, `\my_function:n` shouldn't try to do any particular treatment such as expansion on this argument.
2. Tell LaTeX3 to generate a `V` variant of the base function:

   ```latex
   \cs_generate_variant:Nn \my_function:n { V }
   ```

Said like this, this seems verbose and not so impressive. But you can do this for all arguments, and then you gain tremendously in readability, simplicity, and clarity of the code as compared to an equivalent solution made with `\expandafter` (see the example below with two arguments and your code after my changes—four arguments passed to `\matrixx_draw_node_aux:VVxV`, the third of which is fully expanded before the result is passed to the base function `\matrixx_draw_node_aux:nnnn`, the other arguments being expanded once each to get the value of the corresponding token list variable).

`V` is only one of the available types of variants. There are also `x` variants corresponding to an `\edef` (see sample use in my suggestion for your code), `e` variants similar but usable in expansion-only contexts (they are slow on non-recent TeX engines), `c` variants which do a `\csname ... \endcsname` before passing the resulting control sequence token to the base function, `o` variants which perform one expansion step on the argument, etc. The variants used can be different for each argument, and they are as simple to generate as in the above example.

Other example. Suppose you have a function `\my_other_func:Nn` accepting two arguments, the first of which is a control sequence name and the second of which a list of tokens (a ”normal” argument: type `n`). Suppose that at some point of your programming, you need:

- to pass for the first argument of `\my_other_func:Nn` a control sequence token that isn't very convenient to enter or is dynamically built from several pieces, so that you'd rather input `\my_other_func:cn { difficult@#1@to@enter } { abc~def }` (where `#1` has a suitable value from the surrounding code—could be an identifier) than `\expandafter \my_other_func:Nn \csname difficult@#1@to@enter \endcsname { abc~def }` (using LaTeX2e style);
- to use for the second argument the value of a token list variable (or integer, str, etc.), so that the preceding moderately complicated code with `\csname` needs to be made even more complex to expand once what comes after the `\endcsname` before `\my_other_func:Nn` is itself expanded. Let's call this variable `\l_my_tl` again to straighten out ideas, but it could be something else, for instance a parameter token like `#7`.

Then all you need to do with `expl3` is to define `\my_other_func:Nn` in the most straightforward way, then execute:

```
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \my_other_func:Nn { cV }
```

and use for instance code such as:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Nn \my_caller_func:n
  {
    % Typically set \l_my_tl here, for instance by concatenating elements
    % from a sequence, or anything else.
    (...)
    \my_other_func:cV { difficult@#1@to@enter } \l_my_tl
  }
```

Easy to read, easy to write, very clean and readable. Good use of variants makes clear precisely how and when everything passed to downstream functions is expanded.

## Suggestion for fixing your code

For your code, I propose the following:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}

\tikzset{Matrixx/body/.style={
            draw,
            rounded corners,
            inner sep=2pt,
            outer sep=0pt,
         },
         Matrixx/dim/.style={
            draw=none,
            font=\footnotesize,
            outer sep=2pt,
            inner sep=3pt,
         }
}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_matrixx_name_tl
\tl_new:N \l_matrixx_minimum_height_opt_tl
\tl_new:N \l_matrixx_minimum_width_opt_tl
\tl_new:N \l_matrixx_content_tl
\tl_new:N \l_matrixx_options_body_tl
\tl_new:N \l_matrixx_options_dim_tl

\keys_define:nn { Matrixx }
  {
    name .tl_set:N = \l_matrixx_name_tl,
    name .value_required:n = true,

    minimum~height .code:n = {
      \tl_set:Nn \l_matrixx_minimum_height_opt_tl { minimum~height = #1 } },
    minimum~height .value_required:n = true,
    minimum~height .initial:n = { 1cm },

    minimum~width .code:n = {
      \tl_set:Nn \l_matrixx_minimum_width_opt_tl { minimum~width = #1 } },
    minimum~width .value_required:n = true,
    minimum~width .initial:n = { 1cm },

    content .tl_set:N = \l_matrixx_content_tl,
    content .value_required:n = true,

    options/body .tl_set:N = \l_matrixx_options_body_tl,
    options/body .value_required:n = true,

    options/dim .tl_set:N = \l_matrixx_options_dim_tl,
    options/dim .value_required:n = true,
  }

\seq_new:N \l__matrixx_draw_node_tmp_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \matrixx_draw_node:n #1
  {
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn { Matrixx } {#1}

    % Collect in \l__matrixx_draw_node_tmp_seq the additional options to pass
    % to the matrix body node.
    \seq_clear:N \l__matrixx_draw_node_tmp_seq
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__matrixx_draw_node_tmp_seq
                      \l_matrixx_minimum_height_opt_tl
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__matrixx_draw_node_tmp_seq
                      \l_matrixx_minimum_width_opt_tl
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__matrixx_draw_node_tmp_seq
                      \l_matrixx_options_body_tl

    % Concatenate the arguments we assembled with a comma separator, then call
    % the base function passing it the values of the other tl variables.
    \matrixx_draw_node_aux:VVxV
      \l_matrixx_name_tl
      \l_matrixx_content_tl
      { \seq_use:Nn \l__matrixx_draw_node_tmp_seq { , } }
      \l_matrixx_options_dim_tl
    \group_end:
  }

% #1: matrix name (stem of the two nodes)
% #2: matrix node contents
% #3: options to pass to the body node
% #4: additional options to pass to the 'dim' node (whatever this means...)
\cs_new_protected:Npn \matrixx_draw_node_aux:nnnn #1#2#3#4
  {
    \node [ Matrixx/body, #3 ] (#1/body) {#2};

    \node [ Matrixx/dim, anchor = south, #4 ]
          (#1/dim/top) at (#1/body.north) {n};
  }

% 'x' stands for “full eXpansion” and 'V' for “value” (here: of token list
% variables; i.e., their contents).
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \matrixx_draw_node_aux:nnnn { VVxV }

\NewDocumentCommand \DrawMatrixx { m }
  {
    \matrixx_draw_node:n {#1}
  }

% Convenient function for setting defaults at document level. It respects the
% normal TeX grouping rules (in other words, the settings are not \global).
% You can use it in various parts of your document to override the initial
% values set by the above \keys_define:nn call.
\NewDocumentCommand \MatrixxSetup { m }
  {
    \keys_set:nn { Matrixx } {#1}
  }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \DrawMatrixx{
      name=Name,
      content=H,
      options/body={
          thick,
          text=blue,
      },
      options/dim={
          text=red,
      }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]

## The particular case of Ti*k*Z

The Ti*k*Z parser is rather forgiving; one noteworthy property of this parser is that it often takes care of expanding user macros written inside the `tikzpicture` environment so that these macros can generate valid Ti*k*Z code that the parser will then successfully process. Indeed, if you think about our code here, it wouldn't work with a very “rigid” parser, because `\DrawMatrixx` is not a command described in the Ti*k*Z & PGF Manual! So, `\DrawMatrixx` is expanded by Ti*k*Z instead of being reported as un unexpected command, and the parsing continues with the result. With a more rigid parser, we would have needed to write something like:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \my_function:n #1
  {
    \begin{tikzpicture} #1 \end{tikzpicture}
  }
```

and called `\my_function:V` with for instance a token list variable containing the computed program in Ti*k*Z language, dropped directly between the `\begin{tikzpicture}` and `\end{tikzpicture}`. That would be the bullet-proof way, but Ti*k*Z trying hard to expand user-provided contents, we can avoid this hassle.

So, in many cases, especially when `expl3` isn't used, you can obtain shorter code by letting the Ti*k*Z parser expand things himself, instead of carefully preparing the figure code so that it only contains Ti*k*Z commands and “constants.” People do it all the time, probably not all of them realize. In my example, you can check that replacing the `VVxV` variant by `nnxV`<sup>1</sup> results in working code. But that doesn't work with `nnxn`, so what automagically works is not so easy to predict...

You'll probably do it sometimes, but it's good to understand how to properly prepare the Ti*k*Z input, because this skill will help you all the time with LaTeX programming (in my humble opinion). Relying on luck, hoping that a command will expand your arguments (or environment body) the way you need, etc., is not something I find fun and can lead to severe headaches when it doesn't work. Learning to precisely control when and how things are expanded in order to feed a command or environment input exactly as if you had written it by hand is very useful, and makes you able to solve many automation problems: if you can do something in TeX by hand and know how to generate the same input programmatically, you can automate it.

## On the official `expl3` documentation

I suggest you also read the other documents from the [“l3kernel” link](https://ctan.org/pkg/l3kernel) I mentioned to get more familiar with `expl3`. They are all rather short except [The LaTeX3 interfaces](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf), which is a reference manual and doesn't have to be read from cover to cover. For that one, my suggestion is to carefully read the table of contents to get an idea of what is available, skim through or read the first chapters depending on the time you have, and then refer to the rest of the document on an as-needed basis (I need to do this and that, sequences [for instance] may be the right tool; let's see what the intro of their chapter says; yes, this is what I need; let's see what functions are available → try them → problem solved).

If you really look at these documents, you'll see that there is presumably nothing you need to read in the *Syntax changes* document now—being simply aware of its existence is probably enough. In my opinion, when starting with `expl3`, [The LaTeX3 Pro­gram­ming Lan­guage](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf) also known as `expl3.pdf`, and the [LaTeX3 style guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/l3styleguide.pdf) also known as `l3styleguide.pdf`, are really very important; reading them at the beginning shouldn't take very long and is really a time investment.

Unrelated: as I said in comments, `\tikzstyle` is deprecated, I've replaced it with `\tikzset` in your code.

---

**Footnote**

1. In the `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` and where `\matrixx_draw_node_aux:VVxV` is called. You may want add braces around the first two arguments in the resulting `\matrixx_draw_node_aux:nnxV` call for this test to be really clean. Regarding these braces, [The LaTeX3 interfaces](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf) says:

   > Usually, if you use a single token for an `n` argument, all will be well.

   I let you appreciate the term “usually”. :-)

Comment: Thank you for your time, efforts and output great solution and tutorial! Such a dope. Need some time to digest and study.

Comment: I hope you'll make good use of it. :-) I added a little complement concerning the Ti*k*Z parser—it is eager to expand user macros, and this property often allows to “simplify” code... when it works.